# Applying text color via class doesn't work in a VisualForce page

Tags: css, salesforce, visualforce

I'm observing a strange behavior in a VisualForce page. I defined a css class and apply it to a couple of elements as follows:

```
<apex:page>
...
<style>
  .lnk
  {
      color:SteelBlue;
      text-decoration:none;
  }
</style>
...
<a class="lnk" href="/{!item.id}/e?retURL=/{!IRM_id}" target="_parent">Edit</a> 
<apex:commandLink styleClass="lnk" action="{!deleteAttachment}" value="Del">
...
</apex:page>
```

For some reason the **text-decoration** style is applied, but the **color** doesn't change. I'm not very good with css intricacies, can someone explain to me what's happening here?

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/QZnSL/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think some of styles are applied by Salesforce via JS so the normal order of execution fails. Normally you'd expect first to apply SF styles, then your own additions. I have the same when I need to bypass some specific styling that comes with jQuery plugins.

You might try with [`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html) applied. It works for me, whether it's a right way to do is probably an [entirely different discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css)...

```
.lnk {
    color: SteelBlue!important;
    text-decoration :none;
}
```

Hope someone will point out something obvious & simpler!